# Multiple strings to inntegers in SAS

Tags: arrays, macros, sas, do-loops

I have a series of string variables (x, y, z) whose observations I need to change from strings (x= less than 1 mile, more than 1 mile less then 5 miles, etc.) to integers (xrecode= 1, 2, etc).

Is there any automated way to do this? I need an automated method that gets away from this values equal 1, that value equals 2, ...(Do Loops, Arrays, Macros welcome)?

Comment: Formats and/or a lookup table. Most likely a format. If you want more beyond that post more details, including a sample of what you have, what you expect and most importantly, what you've currently tried.

Comment: I need help figuring out building co Hde to select multiple variables with missing values.
Beginning code:

 PROC SQL;
SELECT x INTO :x SEPERATED BY " "
FROM have;
QUIT;

%let x = &x;

Comment: Post what you've tried by editing the questions, not by including code in the comments. That's not legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an INFORMAT to convert from text to integer.

```
proc format ;
  invalue distance 
   'less than 1 mile'=1
   'more than 1 mile'=2
   'less then 5 miles'=3
  ;
quit;
```

You can apply the same operation to multiple similar columns by looping over an ARRAY.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array in x y z ;
  array out nx ny nz ;
  do i=1 to dim(in);
    out(i)=input(in(i),distance.);
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reeza is right. Proc format for instance:

```
proc format; 
    value ToForm 
    low-1 = 'less than one'
    1-5 = 'one to five'
    5-high = 'over five'
;quit;

data wanted;
    set begin;
    format val_to_format ToForm.;
run;
```

For more on proc format see: [SAS documentation: proc format](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p1upn25lbfo6mkn1wncu4dyh9q91.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

Comment: Sounds to me like OP wants an informat, to go from character to numeric.